CodeIgniter not sending email through SMTP
I have migrated my CodeIgniter 4 app from a shared hosting to a VPS but now the application is not sending emails, this is the return I am getting when processing the pending mails to be sent:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

I am using an email address that works fine, at least from my Thunderbird client using port 465. But when trying to send emails CodeIgniter 4 gives the error even if it is configured to use the same email account:
email.protocol = 'smtp';
email.SMTPHost = 'mail.mydomain.com';
email.SMTPUser = 'myname@mydomain.org';
email.SMTPPass = 'mypassword';
email.SMTPPort = 465;
email.SMTPCrypto = 'ssl';
email.mailType = 'html';
email.newline = "\r\n";

The code worked perfectly in my previous server, so the only differences are

The email configuration on the app (previous code).
The way the server sends emails.

I have also tried using 587, and all combinations of ssl/tls/blank in SMTP Crypto. I have also written the SMTP port between ''.
In the server I have disabled grey-listing and spam features.
What is the problem?
UPDATE 1:
This is the log of my email server:
2024-10-29 00:26:27 info    
postfix/cleanup [6029]
    6B71FC48E5: message-id=<67201d855649e5.77105247@mydomain.com>
2024-10-29 00:26:27 err 
psa-pc-remote [6019]
    Message aborted.
2024-10-29 00:26:27 err 
psa-pc-remote [6019]
    Message aborted.
2024-10-29 00:26:27 info    
postfix/smtpd [6025]
    disconnect from mail.mydomain.com[MY_IP] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=0/1 commands=4/5
2024-10-29 00:26:27 info    
postfix/smtpd [6025]
    lost connection after DATA (525 bytes) from mail.mydomain.com[MY_IP]
2024-10-29 00:25:57 info    
psa-pc-remote [6019]
    6B71FC48E5: from=<sender@mydomain.com> to=<recipient@externaldomain.com>
2024-10-29 00:25:57 info    
postfix/smtpd [6025]
    6B71FC48E5: client=mail.mydomain.com[MY_IP], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=sender@mydomain.com
2024-10-29 00:25:57 info    
postfix/smtpd [6025]
    connect from mail.mydomain.com[MY_IP]

UPDATE 2:
I have somehow guessed changing email.protocol = 'smtp' to either 'mail' or 'sendmail'... and email is being sent!!!
That's because my email server is in localhost.
I don't know the reason for SMTP failing, while I can access the email through SMTP from an email client, though.

Sorry - you're using Plesk - your question is off topic here. Your MTA is telling you that the client (your PHP code) is terminating the connection before completing the send. You shouldn't be using ssl here.

Most VPS providers block SMTP ports. Make sure that they are allowed or contact your provider. They may be disabled for security, but may be enabled if necessary.

As I said, SMTP is working because I can use all email accounts through SMTP using email clients such as Thunderbird. It's something related with connecting to SMTP from the web server.
